# Determine whether subspaces are compact(and why)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

[image]

Attempt at a solution:
Facts I know:

A closed subset of a compact space is compact.

A compact subset of any metric space is closed.

A finite union of compact sets is compact

A subset A of R^n is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

a. This subset is the set of all points on the x-axis and the set of all points on the y-axis.  Since this subset is not bounded, it is not compact.

b.  This subset is closed as it contains all its limit points(not sure if this correct actually).  It is also bounded as we are going from x=0 to 1 and y=0 to 1.  Hence it is compact.

c.  For this one, the lim rn=+infinity throws me off a bit.  I know in polar coordinates x=rcos(theta),y=rsin(theta) is just a circle. I know cosine and sine are both bounded.  Honestly, not too sure about this one, don't have too much intuition.

d.  I plotted this in wolfram alpha and it is a square shape with side length 2.  Because of the equals, the boundary is contained so it is closed and by the picture it is bounded. This is probably not proper reason so I need help formalizing a proper reason or argument for this.

Comment: For b: If you want a more formal way to prove that the set is closed, I find it easier to prove that its complement is open: any point in said complement has strictly positive distance to your set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a. Correct.

b. Correct.

c. **Hint**: try to look at the norm of $(r_n\cos n\phi, r_n\sin n\phi)$

d. The set is closed because it is a preimage of $\{1\}$ using a continuous function. To see that it is bounded, you can show that if $|x|>1$, then $x^6+y^6>1$ (and the same if $|y|>1$).

Comment: is the norm for part c just 1 or am i mistaken?

Comment: @kemb Apply the definition of norm, and keep in mind that $\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\phi = 1$.

Comment: I think I am confused.  What do you mean by norm in this sense?

Comment: @kemb The norm of a vector $(x,y)$ is $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Comment: So the norm in this case would be sqrt(rn^2(cos ntheta)^2 +sin(ntheta)^2)).          We pull out the rn and get rn(sqrt(cos(ntheta)^2+sin(theta)^2))=rn(sqrt(1))=rn.  Since rn goes to infinity, we know it is unbounded.

Comment: This implies that the norm of $(r_n\cos(n\phi), r_n\sin(n\phi))$ is $\sqrt{r_n^2(\cos^2(n\phi)+\sin^2(n\phi))} = \lvert r_n\rvert$. As this diverges to $\infty$, the set in c) clearly can't be bounded, since we can find points arbitrarily far from the origin.

Comment: @kemb Correct. Now, simplify that expression (and remember, $\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha =1$ no matter wat $\alpha$ is)

Comment: Great I figured out .

Comment: Thank you for the help on that one.

Comment: @kemb Remember, if an answer is what you need, you can also accept it.

Comment: For future reference, I highly recommend learning LaTeX and [MathJaX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Questions are generally required to be submitted here using MathJax.

Comment: Yeah, I know MathJax.  I'm just not very adept at it, so it takes me a very long time to type out several lines.

Comment: Practice makes perfect! I typed all of my homeworks, and even class notes, in LaTeX starting in my 2nd year of university. It still amazes my colleagues now how quickly I can convert math to LaTeX on the fly (this is definitely aided by the fact that I can type very quickly).

Answer (score 1):

For c): I'd start with checking whether this set is bounded or not (by definition)

For d) you have $x^6 +y^6=1$, hence $x^6\le 1$, hence $|x|\le1$. Similarly for $y$, this gives you boundedness. The closedness comes from the fact that the function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$, $f(x,y)=x^6+y^6$ is continuous.